# Olap analysis and Reporting

Tags: ssas, reporting, olap

please could someone tell me why some people do this after creating our data warehouse we create report (Repporting ) and  Olap analysis[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh3QR.png)

my question why will we do olap analysis and we create repport what is the Beneficial of doing both of them , i think reporting is sufficient to help the client to analyse the data.But still some client ask for both .

Answer (score 0):

I use Analysis services models as the source for all reporting. In your case you may have transactional reporting (large amounts of row-level data) which doesn't lend itself to the technology. Analysis services would be better suited to data which is likely to be aggregated.

Tabular models are a great way to present data to users for them to interact with as they can be designed in a way which makes them better for self-service data analytics.

I've also implemented the hybrid approach you mentioned. This can be useful if businesses have varying report requirements. For example dashbiarding could be done using power bi connected to the tabular model whereas transactional reporting such as large emailed spreadsheets could be run from the sql server (perhaps using ssrs or power bi paginated).